# GTK - Run function on window close

Tags: c, callback, window, gtk

I'm trying to run a simple function when the 'x' button is clicked in my GTK window but am having trouble getting this to work. I get this error every time I run it:

`(process:17950): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:58:51.480: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'delete-event' is invalid for instance '0x55a183d991a0' of type 'GtkApplication'`

Here are my functions:

main():

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    // Set up the application and start it
    app = gtk_application_new ("com.sds.hashcrack.server", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (init), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (app, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK (test), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

test():

```
gboolean test(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event, gpointer   user_data) {
    g_print("Closed");
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "delete-event" signal is available on [`GtkWidget`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) instances, not on [`GtkApplication`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) ones.

You will need to connect the `test` callback to the `delete-event` signal on the `GtkWindow` you're adding to your application.